# How Can Show Bitmap Image In Div,Span,Label etc. on the Asp.Net ? Don't Use Handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, bitmap

I want to show been bitmap image in Div. I want to do from code behind. I want not to use handler.

Like This:

```
div.InnerHtml = BitmapImage;
```

Comment: where your image lives ? In memory or in file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Pretty simple road to follow (note that you'll be sending a lot of data) :**

Convert the image from bitmap to JPG

Get the base64 for the image (example of base64 image at http://jsfiddle.net/3sdGJ/)

Add the image by writing:

```
div.InnerHtml = "<img alt=\"\" src=\"data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODl.......\"/>";
```

**The preferred way would be to save the image as JPG on the server and then**

```
div.InnerHtml = "<img src=\"pathtoimage.jpg\"/>";
```